# Istanbul nyc to exclude test files

Tags: unit-testing, mocha.js, istanbul

I'm currently getting my test files in the final coverage. That's probably because they sit alongside my components instead of having their own **test** folder.
How can I exclude these from the coverage?

I have installed **istanbul** and **nyc** and I'm using **mocha**.

My script looks like:

`"test": "nyc --reporter=html mocha tools/testSetup.js app/**/*.spec.js || true"`

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Right, after some digging I've managed to get this working. I've added

```json
"nyc": {
    "include": "app", // Only looks in the app folder
    "exclude": "**/*.spec.js" 
}
```

to my `package.json`. Since I'm using **webpack** I'll probably try and find a way of defining this rule in the `webpack.config.js` file (if possible at all). I'll come back if I get an answer to this.

Comment: Just complementing: include and exclude may be arrays.