# nyc (istanbul) exclude test code from coverage reports

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, code-coverage, istanbul, nyc

I'm trying to add coverage report generation to a typescript library project.

The layout includes these directories:

```
project
├─ src
│  ├─ lib      ## project code (typescript), *.tsx
│  ├─ test     ## test specs (typescript), *.spec.tsx
│  └─ @types   ## types I made for a few dependencies that didn't have them
└─ build
   ├─ lib      ## compiled project code (ES5 + type info, with inline sourcemaps), *.js and *.d.ts
   └─ test     ## compiled test specs (ES5 + type info, with inline sourcemaps), *.spec.js and *.spec.d.ts
```

I have a test script in `package.json` that appears to work correctly:

```
    "test": "mocha --reporter mocha-multi --reporter-options mocha-multi=mocha-multi.json --recursive build/test/**/*.spec.js",
```

(it generates 1413 lines of output; currently all tests are passing)

I'm trying to figure out how to run `nyc` so that

1. All tests in `test` are run
2. No files in `test` are included in the coverage report
3. All code files in `lib` are included in the coverage report
4. No type info files in `lib` are included in the coverage report

I think I'm getting #1 right with this command:

```
npx nyc mocha --cache --reporter nyan build/test
```

which has this output:

```
 872 _-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_,------,
 0   _-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_|   /\_/\
 0   _-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-^|__( ^ .^)
     _-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-  ""  ""

  872 passing (20s)

---------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File                 |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
---------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files            |    88.97 |    91.49 |    84.09 |    89.11 |                   |
 lib                 |    88.51 |    91.49 |    83.33 |    88.62 |                   |
  Awaitable.tsx      |    88.51 |    91.49 |    83.33 |    88.62 |... 79,405,419,420 |
 test                |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
  Abortable.spec.tsx |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
  Awaitable.spec.tsx |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
---------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
```

(but more colorful; I'm using `--reporter nyan` because I'd rather not repeat the 1413 lines of output from the test script)

That output fails goals 2 and 3; this question is about goal 2:

**How do I tell nyc to exclude `test` from the coverage report?**

(It also bothers me that the report is wrong - there are no tests that cover other tests, - but that is not what this question is about.)

I've tried adding a variety of includes and excludes to the command, none of which have affected the output:

- -x build/test
- -x '**/*.spec.js'
- -x '**/*.spec.tsx'
- -x 'build/test/**'
- -x test
- -x 'build/test/**/*.spec.js'
- -x 'build/test/**/*.spec.tsx'
- -x 'test/**'
- -x 'test/**/*.spec.js'
- -x 'test/**/*.spec.tsx'
- -n lib
- -n build/lib
- -n src/lib
- -x build/lib
- -x lib
- -x src/lib
- -X test
- -X build/test
- -X src/test

(As you can see, I'm not sure what the basedir is for these; I wasn't expecting to see the source file names in the report, but `nyc` is clearly doing something with both of `src` and `build` but not showing either in the report.)

I tried the include options after reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42115872/776723), and it didn't help.  After adding excludes for lib and seeing no effect, I'm getting the impression that the exclude option just doesn't work.  I won't switch to ES6 as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45463875/776723) until noone I work with still supports IE.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looking at this again after reaching 100% test coverage and wanting `nyc check-coverage --branches 100 --functions 100 --lines 100 --statements 100` to pass I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42115872/776723):

> Right, after some digging I've managed to get this working. I've added
>
> ```
> "nyc": {
>   "include": "app", - only looks in the app folder
>   "exclude": "**/*.spec.js" 
> }
> ```
>
> to my package.json.

Which lead me to this working solution in mine:

```
"nyc": {
  "include": [ "build/lib/**/*.js" ],
  "exclude": [ "build/test/**/*.spec.js", "build/testlib/**/*.js" ]
}
```

(In between I added paths `src/testlib` and `build/testlib` containing helpers used only in tests, which should not be run as tests, and which should be excluded from test coverage reporting.)