# how would i ignore a folder for being included into (coveralls) while running unit testing with mocha chai coveralls

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai, coveralls, nyc

hi I am trying to exclude  given from being added into the coverall  of my tests
the following my test command

```
 "test": "nyc --reporter=html --reporter=text mocha --timeout 10000 --require @babel/register \"./{,!(node_modules)/**/}*.test.js\" --exit",
```

the only thing i managed is to avoid mocha from runnign modules build in tests

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nyc (istanbul) exclude test code from coverage reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50080629/nyc-istanbul-exclude-test-code-from-coverage-reports)

Comment: i am not using Istanbul i am using **coverall**  to get my test code coverage

- mocha
- chai
- coverall
- nyc

Comment: `nyc` = Istanbul (it's confusing, I know) is what's generating the coverage. Coveralls is just where your coverage is displayed. Have you tried the solution from that possible duplicate link?